# Unbalanced bridge resistor current using node analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

I've been trying to solve for the current through the \$ R_5 \$ resistor.

[image]

Those are my findings. I really cannot wrap my head around what happens to the current I as it departs node a. This is bugging me.

I ultimately need to arrive at a solution for this without using Thevenin's equivalent or delta-wye conversion. Rather reach the conclusion delta-wye conversion reaches by means of the node method.

I remember seeing about this in a book, they said something like "...rather focus on the resistance across branches..." but it iss a faded memory I cannot remember it now.

As you can see from the picture, algebraic sense is barely even made. This is just the situation I'm in.

Comment: Your work looked reasonable to me until the last equation. Can you explain how you arrived at that? What do you mean by "what happens to the current as it departs node a"? What don't you understand?

Comment: oh youre right all of them terms but the first one have G_5 in their denominator, my bad.

Comment: by the current departing node a, i mean since V is known to be the voltage at node a, the current however, changes so the equations at node b and c wont include I but a different current since the seemingly parallel configuration divides current. Am I right?